# Emberjs - model doesn't refresh based on dynamic segment in route

Tags: ember.js

In my app I have this route structure

```
Profile.Router.map(function() {
 this.resource('index', { path: '/:user' });
 this.resource('followers', { path: '/:user/followers' });
 this.resource('following', { path: '/:user/following' });
});
```

`/:user/followers` shows a list of followers of ':user'.
Now, when I go from say - `/ross/followers` to `/jack/followers`, the same list of followers for ross is shown for jack's followers route as well. It seems to be because route is a singleton in ember, but what I wish to know is how is such a basic usecase handled in ember. I would want to preserve the models per each /:user/following, but expect it to change for every different 'user'.

UPDATE:
I am using link-to to transition between `/ross/followers` to `/jack/followers`. Here is my route and controller:

```
Profile.ProfileFollowersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('cur_user', this.modelFor('profile').user);
    this._super(controller, model);
  },
  events: {
    fetchPage: function(page, perPage) {
      var that = this;
      Ember.$.getJSON('/'+this.modelFor('profile').user+'/followers/'+page+'?new=1').then(function(items){
        that.get('controller').send('gotMore',items, page);
      });
    }
  }
});

Profile.ProfileFollowersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(InfiniteScroll.ControllerMixin,{
  perPage: 8,
  page: 0,
});
```

The infinite scroll plugin initiates data fetch.

Comment: Can you show me controller code and specify how you try to change the url. Did you used #link-to or transition or hard refresh

Comment: @sushant updated my question with more details. I am facing the issue when using link-to or transition. On hard refresh it works fine.